# Setting up layout with multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am currently working on an android project and I am trying to make use of fragments. I've got it mostly working, however, I can't get the layout right.

In the layout there should be a slide in navigation drawer from the left and a slide in navigation drawer from the right.

At the top of the activity there should be a fragment and underneath that another fragment. The top fragment being smaller than the below fragment.

Even though I have set the height for the fragment it is taking up the whole screen and both fragments are overlapping below. Below is an image which should hopefully highlight what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Screen layout]

Below is the XML for the FragmentActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment android:name="com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager.QueryEditor"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_query_editor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"/>
    <fragment android:name="com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager.MainContentFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />
    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#4e4e4e"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#111" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've taken out the slide in nav menu from the right for the time being just while I get the basic layout correct

Below is the XML for the query editor fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#c1c1c1c1" >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="QUERY EDITOR"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

Your drawer layout should be the outermost parent. You should then have a layout with matchparent height and width that you can use to contain your inner UI fragments. The 2nd and 3rd layouts should be your slide in drawers with the relevant left and right layout_gravity set.

In summary, an outer drawer that contains 3 inner layouts.

Sorry I am on a tablet so can't show this for you but it is all explained here.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html